# Lightweight dynamic WCF client

Tags: c#, json, wcf, dynamic, connection

I have to consume some WCF services but I don't want to implement all necessary classes. Even dynamically. I want to use WCF service as a transport and take care only about important for me things.

Good example would be sending SQL with parameters and get response back.
SQL could be different, parameters different and, of course, response is different. Something is required, something is static, something dynamic - I can take care of all on my side but I don't want to create class for each different case.

Let's take example, assuming that data is passed in JSON.

Request:

```
{ "program":"sqlSelect", "sql":"select siesta from dual"}
```

answer:

```
{"sysdate":"02/03/2016"}
```

Another request

```
{ "program":"sqlSelect", "sql":"select name from user where id<>:a","a":"alex"}
```

response

```
{"rows":[{ "name":"Bob"},{"name":"Bill"}], "errorCode":""}
```

What bothers me is necessity of writing/generating special class for each request/response. 
Of course, general suggestion would be use client/server with simple input/request - just string which contains json. Or, better one, create general object which is complicated enough to handle all possible situations. However, even second example shows how complicated it could be. Worst part - server is not my area. I'm only consumer and can get what server gives me. I can create/transform request to fit server needs but response should be rendered in the simplest possible way.

My assumption is that transport is XML and if it could be intercepted somewhere before it gets translated to object and instead translated to json then I can use something simple like

```
if (answer.errorCode=="") SomeProcess(answer.rows[0].name);
```

without having classes Answer,Rows,Row.

Any suggestions how I can get there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection is the answer. Create service object based on value from json, invoke appropriate service based on json and return answer wrapped to json.
Here is simple code which will invoke any WCF client, call any action, close client and return result as a string:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    class Json2Wcf
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Json2Wcf.CallWcf("{'WcfServiceClass':'MyServiceClient', 'WcfServiceAction':'Heartbeat'}"));
        }

        public static string CallWcf(string json)
        {
            var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

            Type typeWcfServiceClass = Type.GetType(dict["WcfServiceClass"], true);

            object instanceWcfServiceClass = Activator.CreateInstance(typeWcfServiceClass);

            MethodInfo methodWcfServiceAction = typeWcfServiceClass.GetMethod(dict["WcfServiceAction"]);
            object result = methodWcfServiceAction.Invoke(instanceWcfServiceClass, null);

            typeWcfServiceClass.GetMethod("Close").Invoke(instanceWcfServiceClass, null);

            return "Answer="+result;
        }
    }
}
```

of course it returns

```
Answer=thub-thub
```

With a little modification it could invoke actions with parameters and return complex values wrapped into json. 
This example is simple explanation of basic principle how and invoke any WCF service.